# Settings-Applications-Startup list versus ~/.config/autostart

Tags: startup

The author of [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10908/170) question states in a comment that he solved the problem of adding an app to startup by linking its desktop file to `~/.config/autostart`.

Trying to test that I see on my system a big difference between what's there and what really is auto-starting on my system, as some of the apps there are not in the startup list at all, some are disabled, and one app is auto-starting (pcmanfm daemon) without being there.

[image]

What does this mean? Is  `~/.config/autostart` obsolete?

When I delete all desktop files there, the startup list is also emptied.

How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different places from where stuff is autostarted. There are `/etc/xdg/autostart` and `~/.config/autostart` that I know of.

All the stuff, that's not shown in the Startup list is in `/etc/xdg/autostart` probably.
And the apps that are in the settings list are probably in `~/.config/autostart`

`~/.config/autostart` is for applications that only start on login of the current user, while the ones from `etc/xdg/autostart` are started for every one.