# Run AppImage on Startup

Tags: settings, applications, startup

I have an AppImage executable file which I need to run on startup. I have given the file permissions to execute, it is currently 764.

To open the application from terminal, I just the type the path, and it starts. I entered this path as a Custom Command in Settings->Applications->Startup . But it doesn't open on startup. How do i do this?

Comment: If you execute the same command through terminal, does it work correctly, or do you get an error message?

Comment: @RyanDeBeasi It works correctly. I was able to get it working by locating the .desktop file and copying it to autostart folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working by copying the relevant `.desktop` file from `~/.local/share/applications/` to `~/.config/autostart`.

The AppImage I downloaded, when run the first time, gave an option to add shortcut file, which is how the `.desktop` file got in the local folder.

Thanks to [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10932/8796).